# fadeIn element on click and then show another element

Tags: jquery, fadein, visible

I would like to fadeIn an element A on click and then show another element B because element A is visible. Unfortunately my code does not work, can anybody help me?

https://jsfiddle.net/jxma8zfu/17/

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
    $("#hallo").fadeIn();
});
$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
    $("#hallo").fadeOut();
});



$(function() {
    if($("#hallo").is(":visible")) {
        $("#cursor").fadeIn(1000); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one event handler for `toggle` div and check its visible or not depending this hide/show your other elements .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
  //check if hallo is visible means we need to hide..(toggle) 
  if ($("#hallo").is(":visible")) {
    $("#hallo").fadeOut();
    $("#cursor").fadeOut(1000);
  } else {
    //show...
    $("#hallo").fadeIn();
    $("#cursor").fadeIn(3000);
  }
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#hallo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

#cursor {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  background: yellow;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 999999 !important;
  font-size: 2.0em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="toggle">
  toggle
</p>

<p id="hallo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</p>

<div id="cursor">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Hi try like this : `$(document).on('click', function(e) { if (!$('#toggle').is(e.target)) { $("#hallo").fadeOut();$("#cursor").fadeOut(1000);}});` see that works .

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance to also close #hello once the user has clicked somewhere in the viewport? I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
$(window).on("click", function () {
    $("#hello").fadeOut();
});
```